# Per-location view settings or columns layout Per Folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, view, settings

Please help with the following issue.

I just want to select different view setting per folder.
I have tried everything and it does not work.
I tried Per-location view settings or modify view to be applied to specific folder and it does not work.
Εvery time I browse the folders, all the folders have the same view.
Εvery time I show or hide columns in specific folder, all the folders have the same columns.
This is not normal and I can not understand the way sharepoint works.

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1):

Go to library settings> Metadata navigation settings> Add **Folders** and **Content Type** to the **Selected Hierarchy Fields** box, and then click **OK**.

[image]

Now, when you locate the document library, you see a tree view on the left. You can see the views based on locations by clicking the folders from the tree view only. These views will not show when you click the items in the library view on the main part of the page.

[image]

**Per my test this will only work in classic experience.**

For more information, please refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/per-location-view-settings-fail-working